# GetNetworkUsageAsync() in windows Phone 8.1 (C#)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I want to use GetNetworkUsageAsync to get bytes send and receive.
When I do like this, GetNetworkUsageAsyncHandler called But not immediately.
I want to use BytesSent and BytesReceived immediately.
What can I do?

```
private void MakeDataUsageChart()
    {
        //Make days of Month
        GregorianDates = MakeMonthGregorianDate(YearGregorian, MonthGregorian);

        localTime = new DateTime(2015, 9, 2, 0, 0, 0);
        StartTime = new DateTimeOffset(localTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(localTime));
        localTime = new DateTime(2015, 9, 3, 0, 0, 0);
        EndTime = new DateTimeOffset(localTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(localTime));
        InternetConnectionProfile.GetNetworkUsageAsync(StartTime, EndTime, DataUsageGranularity.Total, new NetworkUsageStates()).Completed = GetNetworkUsageAsyncHandler;

        for (int count = 0 ; count <= GregorianDates.Count -1 ; count++)
        {
            ChartDatasGregorian.Add(new Data()
            {
                CategoryDownload = GregorianDates[count],
                ValueDownload = BytesReceived,
                CategoryUpload = GregorianDates[count],
                ValueUpload = BytesSent,
                CategoryTotal = GregorianDates[count],
                ValueTotal = BytesReceived + BytesSent
            });
        }
        this.DataUsageLineSeries.DataContext = ChartDatasGregorian;
    }
    private void GetNetworkUsageAsyncHandler(IAsyncOperation<IReadOnlyList<NetworkUsage>> asyncInfo, AsyncStatus asyncStatus)
    {
        if (asyncStatus == AsyncStatus.Completed)
        {
            IReadOnlyList<NetworkUsage> networkUsages = asyncInfo.GetResults();

            foreach (NetworkUsage networkUsage in networkUsages)
            {
                string BytesSents = networkUsage.BytesSent.ToString();
                string BytesReceiveds = networkUsage.BytesReceived.ToString();
                BytesSent = Convert.ToInt64(BytesSents);
                BytesReceived = Convert.ToInt64(BytesReceiveds);

                //Column2DataPlan.Text = BytesSents + "   " + BytesReceiveds;
            }

        }
    }
```

I'm sorry for bad English.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, instead of calling an awaitable method and assigning the `Completed` event, It's better to call the method using await operator and continue your desired logic afterwards.

e.g :

```
await InternetConnectionProfile.GetNetworkUsageAsync(...);
//The content of GetNetworkUsageAsyncHandler can be moved here.
```

I hope it turns out to be helpful.

Comment: @Amin You can find more information about [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I want to say the answer of question. Thank you **Mohammad Chamanpara** a lot.
I just changed it a little:

```
IReadOnlyList<NetworkUsage> asyncInfo = await InternetConnectionProfile.GetNetworkUsageAsync(StartTime, EndTime, DataUsageGranularity.Total, new NetworkUsageStates());

        foreach (NetworkUsage networkUsage in asyncInfo)
        {
            string BytesSents = networkUsage.BytesSent.ToString();
            string BytesReceiveds = networkUsage.BytesReceived.ToString();
            BytesSent = Convert.ToInt64(BytesSents) / 1024 / 1024;
            BytesReceived = Convert.ToInt64(BytesReceiveds) / 1024 / 1024;
        }
```

I hope that this help everyone.
Thanks.